# How necessary is using participles with the verb spend?

Tags: participles

Would you be willing to spend a few moments **to read** the letter I wrote to you?

Would you be willing to spend a few moments **reading** the letter I wrote to you?

Are both the sentences grammatically correct?
Is there a difference in what they mean?

Would you be willing to spend a few dollars **to buy** this? 
In this last sentence, it'd be grammatically incorrect to use the participle **buying**, right?

Comment: You spend time ***doing*** something. Native speakers never spend time ***to do*** anything. Conversely, we can ask if someone can ***spare** [the] time **to do** something*, but we never ask if they can *spare time **doing** it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Take a moment to rethink that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is grammatical, and both have essentially the same meaning.

I might consider the first one as emphasizing the fact that you want the entire letter read, while the second one doesn't expect the reading to be finished after just a few moments.

Your buying example isn't exactly ungrammatical, but it does sound awkward. You could understand it as a shortened form of "Would you be willing to spend some dollars [as part of the process of] buying this?"

Comment: I have rethought my statement, and I still think that idiomatically you're wrong.

Comment: Your OED link is to ***take** [the] time **to** do it*. But we're talking here about [***spend** time to do it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22spend+time+to+do+it%22), which gets just 3 hits in Google Books (only one of which I can read in context anyway). That's compared to over 1000 instances of [*spend time **doing** it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22spend+time+doing+it%22). It's also relevant whether "doing it" represents an ***activity** [requiring time]* or a ***goal***.

Comment: Of the two sentences I used in the question, which would you use ?@FumbleFingers

Comment: @lekon chekon: Per my first comment, ***reading*** is idiomatically streets ahead of ***to read*** in your specific context.

Comment: I'm not sure precisely how to sum up the *activity/goal* distinction, but it seems to me it's more acceptable to say *You should spend [the] time **to learn** this* than, say, *Can you spend a few minutes to listen to this?* primarily because in the first case you're being asked to spend time *pursuing a goal*, whereas in the second it's just an "activity" (which presumably *leads* to some goal).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I got one more question for you.
It's not related to the question I posted here.

I need new friends (who) I can have read my poems.

^is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: @lekon chekon: Yes, that's fine. Pedants might say you should use ***whom*** rather than ***who***, but I'm not one of those (or you can use ***that***, or nothing at all).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you don't think the first sentence is idiomatic, do you?

Comment: @lekon chekon: Spend a few minutes searching Google Books for **spend a** + **minute / moment / few minutes / while / etc.** + **XXXing / to XXX**. Then do the same with **spare**, and I'm sure you'll see there's a huge difference in idiomatic preference. But that's all it is - as chepner says here, both your examples are equally valid grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there's a difference:

> Would you be willing to set aside a few moments to read the letter I
>   sent you?
>
> Would you be willing to spend a few moments reading the letter I sent
>   you?

**to read** is prospective

**reading** is durational